# Polymer : Images are not getting displayed on IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

When I tried to load images as

```
 <img src="../../images/icon.png" alt="Unable to load logo">
```

it works on safari and chrome. However image is not loading in edge and IE 11. I have tried by giving absolute url and setting src property from javascript, but failed. In n/w tab image download request is returing with 304 status. Does anyone face this issue?

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache and try again and can you access to the image in another tab with the same url?

Comment: @Miguel Yes I did. I have opened the url alone in a new tab after deleting cache. alt text is getting displayed, no image.